# Credit card validation - Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, checksum

Just completed a piece of code - a credit card validation program in python - as a little side project. Having no experience with classes in the past, I decided to employ classes in this project.

I am wondering if you could review my code, both appraising the actual code, but also evaluate my use of OOP/classes.

The requirements for the program are:

> The user enters their name, postcode, the card code, and the card
>   date.
>
> The eighth digit of the card code is removed and acts as a check digit
>
> The code is then reversed
>
> The 1st, 3rd, 5th, and 7th digits are multiplied by 2
>
> If the result of the multiplication is > 9, subtract 9 from it.
>
> If the sum of the 7 digits, and the check digit are divisable by 10,
>   the code is valid
>
> The card date must also be in the future.
>
> Finally, output their name, postcode, card number, and whether it is
>   valid or not.

---

The code:

```
"""Program used to check if a credit card is authentic."""
# !/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Check it out
import datetime


class Customer:
    """Class representing the customer and their credit card details"""

    # Constructor
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = input("Name: ")
        self.postcode = input("Postcode: ")
        self.card_date = input("Card date: ")
        self.card_code = input("Card code: ").strip()

    def check_date(self):
        """Checks current date against the credit card's date. If it is valid, returns True; else False."""
        card = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.card_date, "%d/%m/%Y").date()
        if datetime.date.today() < card:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def check_code(self):
        """Contains the algorithm to check if the card code is authentic"""

        code_list = list(str(self.card_code))
        check_digit = int(code_list[7])
        code_list.pop()
        # The last digit is assigned to be a check digit and is removed from the list.
        code_list.reverse()

        for item in code_list:
            temp_location = code_list.index(item)
            if is_even(temp_location):
                code_list[temp_location] = int(item) * 2
        # Loops over each digit, if it is even, multiplies the digit by 2.

        for item in code_list:
            temp_location = code_list.index(item)
            if int(item) > 9:
                code_list[temp_location] = int(item) - 9
        # For each digit, if it is greater than 9; 9 is subtracted from it.

        sum_list = 0
        for item in code_list:
            sum_list += int(item)
        # Calculates the sum of the digits

        code_total = sum_list + int(check_digit)

        if code_total % 10 == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
            # If the code is divisible by 10, returns True, else, it returns False.

    def check_auth(self):
        """Checks the card's authenticity. """
        if self.check_code() and self.check_date():
            print("----------------------")
            print("Valid")
            print(self.name)
            print(self.postcode)
            print(self.card_date)
            print(self.card_code)
        else:
            print("----------------------")
            print("Invalid")
            print(self.name)
            print(self.postcode)


def is_even(number):
    """Function used to test if a number is even."""
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    customer().check_auth()
```

Comment: `"%d/%m/%Y"` most card I know only care about the month and year

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there is this code organization issue - you have a class named `Customer`, but it, aside from the `.name` attribute, consists of credit-card related logic only.

I would also pass the obtained attributes to the class constructor instead of asking for them inside it:

```
def __init__(self, name, post_code, card_date, card_code):
    self.name = name
    self.post_code = post_code
    self.card_date = card_date
    self.card_code = card_code
```

It is a little bit cleaner to do this way since now our class is more generic, it is agnostic of where the attributes are coming from.

Some other *code-style related notes*:

- consistent naming: rename `postcode` to `post_code`
- revise the quality and necessity of comments: there is probably not much sense in having a comment `# Constructor`
- you can simplify the way you return a boolean result from your methods. For instance, you can replace:

  ```
  if datetime.date.today() < card:
      return True
  else:
      return False
  ```

  with:

  ```
  return datetime.date.today() < card
  ```

And, it's worth mentioning that, generally speaking, if you doing this for production, you should not be reinventing the wheel and switch to a more mature, well-used and tested package like [`pycard`](https://github.com/orokusaki/pycard).

Comment: +1 on the passing attributes to the constructor over reading them in with input. I'd also like to also suggest replacing magic numbers with meaningful constants. Giving a good name to a number can replace some comments. You could also consider a Card class, and create a Customer with a name, postcode and CreditCard object.

Comment: The spec quoted in the question uses "postcode" as one word, so I would expect the variable to be `postcode` as one word.